# React checkbox do the filter (sort) after clicked two time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here is a code to represent cards of restaurants and have filters to resort or represent the cards depends which filter is clicked, but I have a small problem here, the filters and sort by methods work after I click the checkbox twice, can you please help me.

here is the full codes, the filters, and sort by codes have comments above and under them to notice

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import App from "../../App";
import Cards from "../../Card";

function CreateCards(resturants) {

//Handel the Music, Wifi, Partition (to transfer it from bolean form into string)
    let ifMusic;
    let ifWifi;
    let ifPartition;

    if (resturants.Music == true){
        ifMusic = "Music";
    }else{
        ifMusic = "No Music";
    }

    if (resturants.Wifi == true){
        ifWifi = "Wifi";
    }else{
        ifWifi = "No Wifi";
    }

    if (resturants.Partition == true){
        ifPartition = "Partition";
    }else{
        ifPartition = "No Partition";
    }
        
    return(
        <Cards
            key={resturants._id}
            theCardId={resturants._id}
            placeName={resturants.Name}
            stars={resturants.Rating}
            PRating={resturants.PRating}
            music= {ifMusic}
            img={resturants.icon} // need uploads file
            status={Status(resturants.OpenTime, resturants.CloseTime)}
            descreption={resturants.Description}
            wifi={ifWifi}
            partition={ifPartition}
        />
    );
}

// Check if the place is open or closed depending on the work hours
function Status (Open, Close){
    const date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    const red = 'red';
    const green = 'green';
    if ((Open <= hours) && (hours < Close)){
        return "Open";
    }else{
        return "Close";
    }
}


export default class Resturants extends Component {
//constructor elemnts in login
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

//intialy no data enterd // the types are the filters for each place such as music wifi etc
        this.state = {
            resturants: [],
            Type1: false,
            Type2: false,
            Type3: false,
            Type4: false,
            Type5: false,
            filteredRestraunts:[],
            noPlaceFound: false
    }
    this.onChangeMusic = this.onChangeMusic.bind(this);
    this.onChangeWifi = this.onChangeWifi.bind(this);
    this.onChangePartition = this.onChangePartition.bind(this);
    this.onChangePriceRatinglow = this.onChangePriceRatinglow.bind(this);
    this.onChangePriceRatinghigh= this.onChangePriceRatinghigh.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount(){
    //Get Resturants data, filteredRestraunts used for filtring and sorting the cards
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/places')
        .then(resp => {
            // console.log(resp)
            this.setState({
                resturants: resp.data,
                filteredRestraunts:resp.data
        })
    })
}

//========================================================//
// Filters
onChangeMusic(e){
    this.setState({Type1: e.target.checked})
    // console.log(this.state.Type1);
    let copy;
    if(this.state.Type1 === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.filter(Type => {return Type.Music === this.state.Type1})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        copy =this.state.filteredRestraunts;
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
    } 
}

onChangeWifi(e){
    this.setState({Type2: e.target.checked})
    // console.log(this.state.Type2);
    let copy;
    if(this.state.Type2 === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.filter(Type => {return Type.Wifi === this.state.Type2})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        copy =this.state.filteredRestraunts;
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
    } 
}

onChangePartition(e){
    this.setState({Type3: e.target.checked})
    // console.log(this.state.Type3);
    let copy;
    if(this.state.Type3 === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.filter(Type => {return Type.Partition === this.state.Type3})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        copy =this.state.filteredRestraunts;
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
    } 
}

//========================================================//
// Sort By
onChangePriceRatinglow(e){
    this.setState({Type4: e.target.checked})
    // console.log(this.state.Type4);
    let copy;
    if(this.state.Type4 === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.sort((a,b) => { return a.PRating.length - b.PRating.length})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        copy =this.state.filteredRestraunts;
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
    }
}

onChangePriceRatinghigh(e){
    this.setState({Type5: e.target.checked})
    // console.log(this.state.Type5);
    let copy;
    if(this.state.Type5 === true){
        copy =  this.state.filteredRestraunts.sort((a,b) => { return b.PRating.length - a.PRating.length})
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
        if(copy.length === 0){
            this.setState({noPlaceFound: true})
        }
    }else{
        copy =this.state.filteredRestraunts;
        this.setState({ filteredRestraunts: copy })
    }
}
//========================================================//

render(){
    
    return(
        <div className="flexthem">
            <div className="Filters">
                <h4>Filters</h4>
                <label>Music
                <input className="Checkbox" type="checkbox"  id="Type1"  onChange={this.onChangeMusic}></input></label>
                <label>Wifi
                <input className="Checkbox" type="checkbox"  id="Type2"  onChange={this.onChangeWifi}></input></label>
                <label>Partiotion
                <input className="Checkbox" type="checkbox"  id="Type3"  onChange={this.onChangePartition}></input></label>
                <label>Price: Sort by</label>
                <label>Lowest to heighest
                <input type="radio" className="RadioBox" id="Type4" onClick={this.onChangePriceRatinglow}></input></label>
                <label>heighest to Lowest
                <input type="radio" className="RadioBox" id="Type5" onClick={this.onChangePriceRatinghigh}></input></label>
            </div>
            <div className="general-card"> 
                {this.state.filteredRestraunts.map(CreateCards)}
            </div>
            <h1 className="noPlaceFound" style={{display: this.state.noPlaceFound ? 'block' : 'none' }}> No place found</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Hi! can you reproduce the situation online in sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get desired outcome always one step later then it means you are getting stale values from state when doing your operation. In order to avoid that you should use useEffect in functional components, or in your case componentDidUpdate for class components. I think after you set states in your onChange functions, you should do the logical operation in componentDidUpdate (move lines starting with "let copy" and followings to componentDidUpdate).